# How to split a Info column in my Dataframe to 6 separate columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, strsplit, tolist

The df dataframe consists of one column called Info which has some words separated by ' '. I want to split these and store them in separate columns.

[image: df Dataframe before the split]

I created the columns and tried the str.split(' ',1).toList() but it shows a ValueError

```
cols = ['Seq','Ack','Win','Len','TSval','TSecr']
df = pd.DataFrame(df.Info.str.split(' ').tolist(), columns=cols)
```

The error that is being shown is -

> ValueError: 6 columns passed, passed data had 87 columns

Answer (score 0):

Simply mentioning the amount of columns to be split in worked.

```
cols = ['Seq','Ack','Win','Len','TSval','TSecr']
df = pd.DataFrame(df.Info.str.split(' ',5).tolist(), columns=cols)
```